# Vocabulary : How to call a Strict linear order associated with a total order relation?

Tags: definition, order-theory

Let $\leq_t$ be a total order relation over a set X.

I want to define "the" strict linear order relation $<_t$ associated with $\leq_t$.
Firstly , is there a name for such a associated relation ?

Secondly , what's the best description (or a good description that does not permit counter example or non sense) for it ?

I would write that , < needs to be transitive , trichotomous , and that for each $x ,y\in X$,$x<_t y\Rightarrow x\leq_t y$ , but i'm not sure it's a good description.

Comment: This is essentially answered on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Strict_total_order), I think.

Comment: Thanks that's what i was looking for , the wikipedia page in my country was not that complete.